# Blender will not render audio visualizer

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

So when I had windows 7 I had no problem with this but since I upgraded to windows 10 every time I render the project which is just an image with an audio visualizer it only renders the image and the sound. I set it to render with CPU and GPU and both doesn't work. I searched on google for answers and can't find anything. Anyone knows why it's doing this?

Here's a gif of how its supposed to render:
https://gyazo.com/7f639435f906ad07bedde9689198896a

And this is how it actually renders it:
https://gyazo.com/280c6e34ae37a12ecba6a58854fdb99d

just the image... 
As I said when I had Windows 7 I never had this issue.

Comment: share the blend file. http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Did you update your version of blender when you updated to Windows 10?